# Read multiple matrix from a file using dinamic allocation in c

Tags: c, matrix

I have an input file like this:

```
3 
7 12 1
1 3 3
2 3 0
12 0 11
7 4 1
1 0 0
```

The first character tells me the size of the square matrix. Then I have a word that indicates the action to be done and then the matrix. I can't find a way to read the first matrix, use it, deallocate it and then move on to the second and so on. Any help? (I'm using c)
I think I found a solution to allocate the matrix using this code:

```
int** Matrix;
int n, i;
fscanf(Data, "%d", &n);
Matrice = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
Matrix[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
```

But this works for the first matrix and I don't know how to treat next matrices to not waste too much memory...

Comment: What do you mean by reading and using the matrix? Do you mean saving the numbers in a 2d array?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You can read the file line by line and parse it. After you know about the size you can allocate a 2 dimentinal array to save the input.

Comment: @George yes I mean saving in a 2d array, but I need to use 1 one matrix at a time

Comment: I thought about solutions but I'm not able to implement a code. I'm still doing a lot of errors

Comment: @HydraStack Please edit your post to include those solutions you have tried so far. See how to ask homework questions: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/12307084](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/12307084)

Comment: @George sorry for the mistakes. I edited the post!

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop that stops when you reach the end of the file, and create a new matrix with each iteration. This way, you can free each matrix before creating a new one. 
(To simplify, this example code works without "ReadMatrix" rows in the input file)

```
    int stop = 0;
    while(stop != 1){
        Matrix = (int**)calloc(n, sizeof(int*));
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            Matrix[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                if(fscanf (Data, "%d", &Matrix[i][i]) == EOF)
                    stop = 1;
            }
        }
        //Use the matrix here
        //...
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            free(Matrix[i]);
        free(Matrix);
    }
```

Example input:

```
3 
7 12 1
1 3 3
2 3 0
12 0 11
7 4 1
1 0 0
```